# Youtubeplayer swift 3 error

Tags: swift3

Hi I am getting this error message in my xcode project.

> //Thread 1: EXC_BAD ACCESS(code = 2,address =DX10f8d3b28)

```
import UIKit

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var youtubeplayerview:YouTubePlayerView!

    var videoURL: URL! = URL(string:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Inn2K-V3NFI")

    override func viewDidLoad() {

     super.viewDidLoad()

        if videoURL != nil {

            youtubeplayerview.loadVideoURL(videoURL) 

            //Thread 1: EXC_BAD ACCESS(code = 2,address =DX10f8d3b28)

        } else
        {
        ...
        }

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     }

}
```

Comment: I meant I created a viewcontroller called "PlayerViewController"

Comment: which framework you are using to play youtube video ?

Answer (score 0):

That seems that your `YouTubePlayerView` - outlet is not connected.

So make it optional to validate

```
@IBOutlet weak var youtubeplayerview:YouTubePlayerView?
```

And then

```
if let myPlayer = youtubeplayerview { 
    myPlayer.loadVideoURL(videoURL)
} else {
    print("na na na ... ")
}
```

You can also remove the nil check for the videoURL, you declared it as *implicitly unwrapped optionals* https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Sounds good Ok I will try to use optional in subclass as you recommended . If does not work I will let you know thanks

Comment: Could you upload the project somewhere (https://github.com), then I'll have a look around

Comment: It works,  you are the man. You were right it was not the code the connection was wrong. I connected the outlet then deleted it when I sent you error from last time. Then I reconnected outlet not realizing the old outlet was still their in the back end. This is what was causing error. To trouble shoot I deleted the view and I deleted the playerviewcontroller . I recreated them both again from scratch and I connected outlet to view and I assigned the viewcontroller to playerviewcontroller added code again   and voila presto! It  works thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

It  worked my iboulet was not connected in main storyboard thanks.

Comment: I wanted to close out this threaded discussion . I was not sure how to go about it .